# How to append content of .txt file to another .txt file line by line?

Tags: shell

So i have a 1.txt file with this content

```
1.1.1.1/0 2.2.2.2/0 9.9.9.9/0
```

I want to append them to a 2.txt file so it would be like:

```
......
1.1.1.1/0
2.2.2.2/0
9.9.9.9/0
```

How should i do that?

Comment: You want to replace blanks by newlines?

Comment: Like @BenjaminW. pointed out, `:%s/ /\r/g` in `vim` would result in a substitution of newline for space. You can then do cat `1.txt >> 2.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way to do this is to *redirect* `file1` using *command-substitution* to `printf "%s\n"` and the result to `file2`. For example, given:

```
$ cat file1.txt
1.1.1.1/0 2.2.2.2/0 9.9.9.9/0
```

You can **create** the `file2.txt` you want using a single `>` (to truncante/create a new `file2.txt`) to *redirect* the output to `file2.txt`, but if you want to **append** to the original content of `file2.txt` as stated in your question, use `>>`, e.g.:

```
$ printf "%s\n" $(<file1.txt) >>file2.txt
```

Which results in appending the following to your `file2.txt`:

```
$ cat file2.txt
## original content
1.1.1.1/0
2.2.2.2/0
9.9.9.9/0
```

(this is generically called the *printf-trick* where `printf "%s\n"` will rely on word-splitting to split a list into as many newline separated individual words as are in the list. It has many other uses. Be wary, if you have more lines than can be held as arguments by the shell, which if I recall correctly is 32767, this may not work)

Another more standard way is to use `tr` to *translate* the `spaces` into `'\n'`, e.g.

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file1.txt >> file2.txt
```

will accomplish the same thing. Also note, that instead of using `' '` for a single space, you can use a *character class* (e.g. `[...]`) and bash provides the POSIX standard character classes such as `alnum alpha ascii blank ...` (see `man bash` for complete list) which can be used within the *character class* as, e.g `[:blank:]` to check for all whitespace characters (`space tab newline`, etc..) instead of just the space. For example:

```
$ tr '[:blank:]' '\n' < file1.txt >> file2.txt
```

(same note on create/append `>/>>`)

You can also use `sed` to do the same thing, e.g.

```
$ sed 's/[ ]/\n/g' file1.txt >> file2.txt
```

The benefit of `sed` is that is allows you to control the replacement of any number of spaces between your addresses. For example, if there were some variable number of spaces or tabs between the addresses, you could handle that with `sed` as:

```
$ sed 's/[ \t][ \t]*/\n/g' file1.txt >> file2.txt
```

Give them all a try, knowing `tr` and `sed` are the more robust solutions, but the *printf-trick* can come in handy as well.

Comment: You'll want `>> file2.txt` since OP specifically requested append.

Comment: OOh Good Catch! Updating.

Comment: Thank you guys so much.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n'` can do the same as your last sed example.